# Font Face Issue in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, font-face

I am using font face "Rockwell Regular". Every browser shows it fine but IE9 is not showing it. I converted the font face here http://www.font2web.com/.

Here is the demo link http://jsfiddle.net/daLQ3/

Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it, Here is the demo link http://jsfiddle.net/daLQ3/1/